# C# - EF 6 Multiple Tables To One FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, ef-fluent-api

I'm designing a database using Code First/Fluent API and faced this question:

How to map a FK that can reference different tables?

This is the scenario:

I have an account chart with a 5-level hierarchy.

From top to botton (one-to-many: Acc1 can have many Acc2 and so on, and Acc2 MUST have a Acc1):

Account1 -> Account2 -> Account3 -> Account4 -> Account5

Example: A supplier can be in any Account Chart: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. (This is a rule in commercial automation).

How to procede with it using fluent API?

[image: DB Model]

Answer (score 1):

Not only is what you're trying to do not possible with EF; it's not possible in a database. A single foreign key can only reference a single table.

If the the data requirements for Account 1-5 are the same, you should consider combining them into a single table with a foreign key that references itself:

```
Accounts
------
AccountId int not null pk
Level (1-5)
ParentId int null fk (references Accounts(AccountId))
OtherColumnsAsNeeded

Supplier
------
SupplierId int not null fk (references Accounts(AccountId))
ParentId int not null fk (reference Accounts(AccountId))
```

This will make modeling in EF much easier. You will still need to maintain certain business rules in code (such as a Level-2 Account must have a Level-1 ParentId).